# Difference between "grub-mkconfig" and "update-grub"

Tags: partition, grub

What is the difference in functionality between `grub-mkconfig` and `update-grub`? Aren't they the same?

Answer (score 3):

The `update-grub` command is a simple shell script wrapper around `grub-mkconfig`.  The wrapper runs `grub-mkconfig` with the arguments `-o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` followed by whatever other arguments are given on the command line of the script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e
exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"
```

(Taken from [Debian's Grub team's Git repository](https://salsa.debian.org/grub-team/grub/-/blob/master/debian/update-grub).)